# Get mean of all columns of a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, multiple-columns, mean

I have a data frame that consists of multiple columns. Each column represents a day in a year (I have 365 columns) and each row is the mean temperature of a specific city. I would like to get the mean of all columns, so I get a mean of temperature for the entire year. I would also like to get the mean of each month (that is mean of 01(January), 02(February), and so on), and also get the mean per quarter of a year.

My data looks something like this

```
data <- data.frame(City = c("London", "Stockholm", "Paris", "Prag", "Berlin", "Copenhagen"), 
                   20100101 = c(4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7), 20100102 = c(2, 5, 8, 6, 1, 3), 
                   20100205 = c(4, 7, 6, 1, 3, 4), 20100305 = c(0, 3, 7, 9, 3, 2), 
                   20100525 = c(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4), 20100719 = c(9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
                   20101011 = c(15, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9), 20101112 = c(3, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   20101212 = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1))
```

How can I extract the mean of the year, each month, and each quarter of a year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier to handle this if you get data in long format.

```
library(dplyr)

long_data <- data %>% 
             tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -City) %>% 
             mutate(name = as.Date(name, '%Y%m%d'))
```

Once you have that you can get yearly, quarterly, monthly mean temperature easily for each city.

```
long_data %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  summarise(year_mean = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Monthly mean :

```
long_data %>%
  group_by(City, month = lubridate::month(name)) %>%
  #For quarter
  #group_by(City, quarter = quarter(name)) %>%
  summarise(month_mean = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I just have a little problem with the first code. When I turn it into a long table and add a row with mutate, I get (in total) three columns. One column with city name and it is filled with the same city, one column named "name" and it is filled with NA (?), and the last one is "value" that is filled with the values from before. Why did i get NA i the "name" column?

Can it be since my columns infact looks like this? 2015_02_15 instead of 20150215?

Comment: @paula456 In that case change the `mutate` line to `mutate(name = as.Date(name, '%Y_%m_%d'))`. You can also use `lubridate`'s `ymd` here like `mutate(name = lubridate::ymd(name))`

Comment: I realized what the problem eas. I was turning a sf object to a sp object and all my data in the column "years" got a X in front of all values. I just added "X%Y_%m_%d" and it worked:) THANKS A LOT!!

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in `base R` with `rowMeans` and `split.default`

```
# // convert the date columns to `Date` class
dates <- as.Date(names(data)[-1], "%Y%m%d")
# // get the row wise mean of numeric columns (except the first column)
city_means <- rowMeans(data[-1])
names(city_means) <- data$City
 
# // split the data into list of data.frame based on the month
# // loop over the list with sapply and get the rowMeans
month_means <- sapply(split.default(data[-1], format(dates, "%b")),
      rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
row.names(month_means) <- data$City

# // split by year quarters and get the rowMeans for each list element
quarter_means <- sapply(split.default(data[-1], paste(format(dates, "%Y"), 
               quarters(dates))), rowMeans, na.rm = TRUE)
row.names(quarter_means) <- data$City
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(City = c("London", "Stockholm", "Paris", "Prag", 
"Berlin", "Copenhagen"), `20100101` = c(4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 7), `20100102` = c(2, 
5, 8, 6, 1, 3), `20100205` = c(4, 7, 6, 1, 3, 4), `20100305` = c(0, 
3, 7, 9, 3, 2), `20100525` = c(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4), `20100719` = c(9, 
10, 5, 6, 7, 8), `20101011` = c(15, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9), `20101112` = c(3, 
7, 1, 1, 1, 1), `20101212` = c(0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```